# NSValue or NSObject subclass

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsarray, nsvalue

In my application I need to put some c-struct-like data into an `NSMutableArray`.
After some research I found that the most suggested solution is to wrap the struct into `NSValue` and insert that into the array.

What about creating a custom subclass of `NSObject` with some properties to match the fields of the struct and insert that into the array?

NSValue is a subclass of NSObject so the overhead in term of performance and memory shouldn't be huge. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You are in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The better idea is to create custom object of NSObject so you can directly access those values as well as insert it into your NSArray, So don't need to convert it into NSValue instead directly create object for that.